# StringBuilder Checking for lettervalues

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I'm trying to change all letters in StringBuilder to hyphens and leave all non letter values alone(such as spaces apostrophes etc), how could I do that without listing and comparing all letters, is that even possible

```
private StringBuilder puzzle = new StringBuilder("I'm the cat")
for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {
    if (puzzle.charAt(i) == ' '){ 
       puzzle.setCharAt(i, ' ');     }
    else 
       puzzle.setCharAt(i, '-');
     }
```

So output would be something like ( -'- --- ---)

Comment: Maybe use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: The Character class has an isLetter() or some similar method that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

.
.
.

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w");

String s = p.matcher("I'm the cat").replaceAll("-");

System.out.println(s);  // prints "-'- --- ---"
```

You can use `<string>.replaceAll("\\w", "-")` as well, but if you're going to be doing lots of replacements in a method, then it's *technically* more efficient to compile the `Pattern` in advance (although admittedly not by very much in this situation).

Answer (score 1):

Try replaceAll():

```
System.out.println("I'm the cat".replaceAll("\\w", "-")); //prints: -'- --- ---
```